# Why this is code is display same result again and again in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to rotate the list like if user input 1 then new list will be `[7,4,5,6,9,8]`, if input 2 new list will be `[8,7,4,5,6,9]`.

without using any predefined function like pop etc

```
list =[4,5,6,9,8,7]
rotate = int(input('How many times you want to rotate : '))
for i in range(0,rotate,1):
    list.insert(0,list[len(list)-1])
    list.remove(list[len(list)-1])
print(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

`list.remove()` deletes the first item found in the list. Since you copied the last item to first item, it will always delete the first item found.
Use `del l[index]` instead.

```
list =[4,5,6,9,8,7]
    rotate = int(input('How many times you want to rotate : '))
    for i in range(0,rotate,1):
        list.insert(0,list[len(list)-1])
        del list[len(list)-1]
    print(list)
```

Comment: Please run this code . list.remove(list[len(list)-1]) always remove the last element .
 
list =[4,5,6,9,8,7]

rotate = int(input('How many times you want to rotate : '))

print("List without removing the element : ")

print(list)

for i in range(0,rotate,1):

      #list.insert(0,list[len(list)-1])

      print('After removing the element ')
      list.remove(list[len(list)-1])
print(list)

Comment: You don't have any duplicate in the list. Why did you comment the insert list line. Uncomment it and test the code.

Comment: I comment the insert line to show you that list.remove(list[len(list)-1])  always remove the last element from the list .
As you said yesterday that it always remove the first item from the list

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
n =  = int(input('How many times you want to rotate : '))
for i in range(0,n):
    l = l[-1:]+l[0:len(l)-1]
    print(l)

Output:

if n = 2
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```